# jQuery Mobile - multiple select - force option listview in dialog

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-mobile, dialog

is there a way to force a `<select multiple>` to open always in a dialog like it is a large list?

Examples at the bottom: [jQuery Mobile Select](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/forms/selects/custom.html)

Thanks for any help.

Regards,
Aley

Comment: Isn't that what happens by default, as is shown in the example? Could you show your code where this is not happening?

Comment: Nope its not. Look at the difference between "Shipping method(s):" and "Choose state(s):" on the jQuery Mobile doc page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay I guess I found a solution.

You can simply set the `.ui-selectmenu` to something like `height: 10000px`.

It will automatically render the select menu as a dialog.

Comment: If you have solved your own issue, you should accept your answer.  This way people can easily tell that the question has been resolved.

Comment: On a related issue, James. I have been trying to force the select to never open in a dialog. Just wondering if you would know if that is possible as well (reducing height .ui-selectmenu to something too small didn't work).